# Hosting 2 blazor server apps(mainsite and admin app) and asp net core web api in same windows hosting package

Tags: asp.net-web-api, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have hosted two blazor server apps and .net core web api in windows package by deploying the main site app in the httpdocs directory which and the other apps in subfolders of the http docs but only the main site app works the rest apps dont work at all. I need to deploy all three apps on same windows hosting package so that I can also share the same domain?

Comment: If you are able to publish it on your main domain, it should be working on your other subdomains or subfolder. If it is not working, what is the error message that you see? Have you published it on correct folder?

Comment: I think you have to create subdomains for each apps.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to answer this question is to demostrate how to do it with the out-of-the-box Blazor templates.

> There are some issues around routing and page reloading you will need to solve once you get the basics working.

Create a Blazor Solution with the Blazor Server template.  Call the solution *Blazor.Medusa* and the project *Blazor.Medusa.Web*.

Add two more Blazor Server projects *Blazor.Medusa.Red* and *Blazor.Medusa.Blue*.

Add Dependencies on *Web* to *Red* and *Blue*.

Change the Sidebar colors on Red and Blue projects so you can see where you are!

MainLayout.razor.css

```css
.sidebar {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 64);
}
```

And

```css
.sidebar {
    background-color: rgb(128, 0, 0);
}
```

Update the Index components in each so they have their "colour" routes.

```html
@page "/"
@page "/Red"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
```

```html
@page "/"
@page "/Blue"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
```

In *Web* add the launch pages for each application.  Add *Red.cshtml* razor page to *Pages*.  Note we're just specifying a different root component for the application.

```
@page "/Red"
@namespace Blazor.Medusa.Web.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<component type="typeof(Blazor.Medusa.Red.App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

And *Blue.cshtml*

```
@page "/Blue"
@namespace Blazor.Medusa.Web.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<component type="typeof(Blazor.Medusa.Blue.App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

Update *_Host.cshtml*

```
@page "/"
@namespace Blazor.Medusa.Web.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<component type="typeof(Blazor.Medusa.Web.App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

Add the additional services to *Web* `Services`.

```cs
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Blazor.Medusa.Red.Data.WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Blazor.Medusa.Web.Data.WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Blazor.Medusa.Blue.Data.WeatherForecastService>();
```

Note I've used the full namespaced class names to ensure clarity.

Update *Web* `Index.razor`.  It's the home page: we need links to Red and Blue.

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="p-2 m-2 text-end">
    <button class="btn btn-primary me-1" @onclick="GoBlue">Go Blue</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger me-1" @onclick="GoRed">Go Red</button>
</div>

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code {

    [Inject] private NavigationManager? NavManager { get; set; }

    private void GoRed()
        => this.NavManager?.NavigateTo("/Red", true);

    private void GoBlue()
        => this.NavManager?.NavigateTo("/Blue", true);
}
```

Hopefully I've covered all the steps and this will now run as I expect.  Add a comment if you're having problems.

Here's some screenshots so you can see what I've got in each project (I've cleared the redundant web stuff out or Red and Blue):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]